# Row counts of all pages in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, pagination, xpath

I have 5 pages(we are using pagination). Each page has 10 records on it.
If i use

```
int rcount =  selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='bank']/tbody/tr").intValue();
```

I am getting rcount as 10, that means it is only getting the 1st page count only
I want to get all records of 5 pages(total 50 records)
Help me...

Comment: I don't know Selenium but I would think this would depend on your web application, and how the different pages are fetched from the server.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to loop over all the pages clicking the next button and summing the values of the row count:

```
int rcount = selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='bank']/tbody/tr").intValue();
while(selenium.isElementPresent("next button locator")) {
    selenium.click("next button locator");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("timeout");
    rcount += selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='bank']/tbody/tr").intValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Selenium works like a browser user!**

So selenium test can only "see" what a use see (if he looks at the HTML code), and do want a user can do.

So if your application has a page size function, you need to set it first to lets say 100. For you selenium test: it means click/invoke the page size function for 100 items first.

Comment: Or you can accumulate the rows in a variable while hitting the next page button until there is no page left.